# how to keep some part of dart code running even app is terminated

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Im using firebase as my remote backend, on my app, users subscribe to some channels and with code I keep watching those streams, when there are changes in the documents of those subscribed streams, I update the local database so the remaining app uses that new data.

this works when app is in foreground or when put to background, but when app is terminated, my app no longer listens to changes of firebase collection, I assume this is because the code is no more running.

Im looking for ways to implement this, once installed, my app should keep doing something irrespective of app state, it should keep listening to the collection and update local database or show some custom notifications.

I haven't tried any as I'm not aware of any plans for this, firebase push messages are one service to trigger app with the event but this is not helping me as some times it delays, or there is no confirmation